# OpenNI eye tracking

Tags: c++, openni, eye-tracking

I'm developing a project with OpenNI.

I've already make a skeleton tracking, but I can't find how can I realize an eye tracking with this library.

Is it possible or I'll have to adapt myself to using Opencv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use Opencv because Openni don't implement the functionality for eye tracking.

Take a look at [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26897/TrackEye-Real-Time-Tracking-Of-Human-Eyes-Using-a)!